# How to apply inversion of pixel position

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

**Goal**

I'm trying to write a program that maps a region of an image to another region in the same image. for instance, if I have a circular region in an image that I want to map every pixel on the circumference of the circle, I would multiply the position of the pixel by some integer to send the pixels outside the region. Basically if you image a ballon, as you fill the ballon with air the surface of the ballon is expanding, similarly you can imagine what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to send every pixel on the surface of the selected circular region to a different place in the image.

**Code**

I started easy, I stated by sending every pixel in a rectangular shaped region to a different place.

```
from PIL import Image
import math
import numpy as np
im = Image.open("gala.png")

width, _ = im.size

#value for the width of image section to be sent
for t in np.arange(0,420):
    xmin=int(115+t)
    xmax=xmin+1
    for i in np.arange(xmin, xmax):
        def getpixels(yaxis):
            pixels=[]
            for j in range(yaxis, yaxis+50):# the value added to yaxis gives value for the height of the image section to be sent
                r, g, b = im.getpixel((i,j))
                pixels.append((r,g,b))
            return pixels

    def replacepixels(yaxis,pixels):
        index=0

        for j in range(yaxis,yaxis+50):
            im.putpixel((i,j),pixels[index])
            index=index+1


        def doalljob(yaxis1,yaxis2):
            firstpart=getpixels(yaxis1)
            secondpart=getpixels(yaxis2)
            replacepixels(yaxis2,firstpart)
        #tells where in y axis to send the pixels
        doalljob(50,220)

im.show()
```

[image: here is the original image]

and then I went further and then mapped every pixel with the region

```
from PIL import Image
import math
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter
import numpy as np
import cv2
im = Image.open("gala1.png")

width, _ = im.size

#value for the width of image section to be sent
for t in range(210,420):
    xmin=115+int(t)
    xmax=xmin+1
    for i in range(xmin, xmax):
        def getpixels(yaxis):
            pixels=[]
            for j in range(yaxis, yaxis+50):# the value added to yaxis gives value for the height of the image section to be sent
                r, g, b = im.getpixel((i,j))
                pixels.append((r,g,b))
            return pixels

        def replacepixels(yaxis,pixels):
            index=0

            for j in range(yaxis,yaxis+50):
                im.putpixel((i,j),pixels[index])
                index=index+1


        def doalljob(yaxis1,yaxis2):
            firstpart=getpixels(yaxis1)
            secondpart=getpixels(yaxis2)
            replacepixels(yaxis2,firstpart)
        #tells where in y axis to send the pixels
        j=int(((t-210)/29)**(5/2))
        doalljob(50,j+130)
for tk in range(0,210):
    xmin=115+int(tk)
    xmax=xmin+1
    for i in range(xmin, xmax):
        def getpixels(yaxis):
            pixels=[]
            for j in range(yaxis, yaxis+50):# the value added to yaxis gives value for the height of the image section to be sent
                r, g, b = im.getpixel((i,j))
                pixels.append((r,g,b))
            return pixels

        def replacepixels(yaxis,pixels):
            index=0

            for j in range(yaxis,yaxis+50):
                im.putpixel((i,j),pixels[index])
                index=index+1


        def doalljob(yaxis1,yaxis2):
            firstpart=getpixels(yaxis1)
            secondpart=getpixels(yaxis2)
            replacepixels(yaxis2,firstpart)
        #tells where in y axis to send the pixels
        j=int(((210-tk)/29)**(5/2))
        doalljob(50,j+130)

im.show()
```

and this is the image I get for the first code

[image]

and this is the image I get for the second code

[image]

which are what I expected

**problem**

The main problem is to select a circular region to send the pixels. I tried methods of using the equation of circle to select a circular region but it ends up in a mess.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you new to python/ programming? Why are your function definitions inside the for loops? O_o

Comment: @TinoD No, I'm not new to python nor am I an expert. The for loop is added last minute, the code was originally supposed to manipulate pixels in bulk so it did not need one of the for loops but I decided to manipulate each column of pixels in the image. I can write the loop inside the functions later on.

Comment: it's currently hard to tell what you are doing since the calls of the functions are hard to follow. Please define the functions outside of the for loops and edit your question accordingly. Only include the call of the function in your for loops.

Comment: Can you post both roi images?

Comment: @TinoD Yes, I can see how my code can be confusing to understand. I'll edit it as soon as I can and update you when I'm done. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As @Tino D pointed out, it is rather hard to understand what you are trying to achieve AND the fact that you have you function definitions inside loops is not helping. But, that being sais, I assume you want an incremental displacement of pixels over the image. I suggest a approch of this type:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def shift_pixels(im_array, x, y_start, y_end, shift):
    """Vertical shift"""
    height = y_end - y_start
    if shift < 0:
        for y in range(y_start, y_end):
            im_array[y+shift, x] = im_array[y, x]
    else:
        for y in range(y_end-1, y_start-1, -1):
            im_array[y+shift, x] = im_array[y, x]

def apply_shift(im, shift_function):
    """Apply a vertical shift to each vertical strip"""
    im_array = np.array(im)
    width, height, _ = im_array.shape
    for x in range(width):
        shift = shift_function(x)
        shift_pixels(im_array, x, 50, 100, shift) 
    return Image.fromarray(im_array)

def shift_function_example(x):
    """Example"""
    if 115 <= x < 325:
        return int(((x - 115) / 29)**(5/2))
    return 0

im = Image.open(r"C:\Users\s-degossondevarennes\Downloads\galaxy.jpg")

shifted_im = apply_shift(im, shift_function_example)

shifted_im.show()
```

Which gives

[image]